# React remove item from nested list

Tags: reactjs

I have a list items:

- Select Dressing

  1. Extra Meat [x]
  2. Extra Potato [x]
- Select Protein

  1. Queso Diablo [x]

Each item have a delete buttons, I want to remove selected item when clicked "x" button, here is my code:

state array:

```
extraOptionsCategory: [
        {
          "name": "Select Dressing",
          "id": 1,
          extraOptions: [{
            "name": "Extra Meat",
            "price": 4
          },
          {
            "name": "Extra Potato",
            "price": 2
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "Select Protein",
          "id": 2,
          extraOptions: [{
            "name": "Queso Diablo",
            "price": 2
          }]
        }
      ]
```

render code:

```
                {this.state.extraOptionsCategory.map((a, index) => {

                  return (
                    <div key={index}>

                      {a.name}

                      {a.extraOptions.map((b, idx) => {
                        return (
                          <div key={idx}>

                            {b.name}

                            <button onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this, idx)}>x</button>
                          </div>
                        )
                      })}

                    </div>
                  )
                })}
              </div>
```

and remove function:

```
removeItem = (idx) => {
    console.log(idx);

    ???
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best if you have a unique id set for each extraOptionsCategory and extraOptions rather than relying on the id being the index from mapping.

The reason is that you are trying to remove something, you want to do that by it's unique id, not it's position in an array that is completely unrelated to the options you are removing.

Use that unique id and set it as the value of attribute of the button.

Pass that value to the removeItem function on the button.

If you are using the index from map, and your array mutates, you might not be removing what you think you are referencing.

```js
extraOptionsCategory: [
        {
          "name": "Select Dressing",
          "id": 1,
          extraOptions: [{
            "name": "Extra Meat",
            "price": 4,
            "id": 1a
          }]
        }]
```

...

```js
<button onClick={(e) => {this.removeItem.bind(this, e.value)}} value={b.id}>x</button>
```